# What is the most efficient method to measure time?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, time

I'm in a situation in which I need to do an action X ammount of times per second (refresh a PictureBox or pull bytes from socket buffer). I was wondering if there is a proper way to do this. I did some research and I found few ways of going about this.

1. I can work in a while loop and constantly ask OS what time is it to check if X ammount of time had passed.(DateTime.UtcNow)
2. I can work in a while loop and put it to sleep for a period of time.
3. I can work in a while loop  and use Clock class to check for elapsed time.
4. Use Timer Class to raise event.

These are all ways I know to make something happen periodically. Second method is not very precise but I put it here for completion sake. Are there other methods I should be aware of? Which one has the least overhead?

I'm working in VisualStudio 2015 C# and version of .NET 4.6.1

Comment: Well a `Timer` is a good `Timer`, what makes you think it would be inefficient/problematical to use one?

Comment: I'm not saying it is bad I'm just asking what's the best approach. I will be using this method possibly hundred times per second and I want to spend relatively as little time as possible on checking what time is it.

Answer (score 2):

Use Stopwatch, which is using high precision timer compared to DateTime.Now

DateTime.Now is good for about milliseconds precision while Stopwatch for microseconds.

```
// Create new stopwatch.
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

// Begin timing.
stopwatch.Start();

// Do something.
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1);
}

// Stop timing.
stopwatch.Stop();

// Write result.
Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);
```

Comment: Sorry for long wait. I was Checking your solution out and how it fits to my problem. Stopwatch class does not seam like a good fit as I can't really find a good way to use it to call a method in a consistant manner. For example the simplest way to implement the stop watch is to check every so often if stopwatch.Elapsed is greater than X and if it is do something then reset the stopwatch. This solution implies some wait period that I have no way to guarante that it will be consistant over long period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Stopwatch is designed for this purpose and is one of the best way to measure time execution in .NET.

```
var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
/* the code that you want to measure comes here */
watch.Stop();
var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

Console.WriteLine(elapsedMs);
```

Do not use DateTimes to measure time execution in .NET.